# couldn't find file 'active_admin/base' with type 'text/css'

Tags: jquery, sass, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am trying to use Active_admin to make an admin app that will allow my non-profit to take attendance of students in our program among other things such as sign permissions, calendar etc. I was trying to make a page for the classroom model called 'Attendance' when the app broke with the above error in the title"Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'active_admin/base' with type 'text/css'". I tried to remove gems, re-install gems and restarted my server many times. I have searched on here and online to no avail, any help I would greatly appreciate.

my application.js

```
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
//= require fullcalendar/gcal
//= require d3
//= require active_admin/base
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2
//= require underscore
//= require autoselect
//= require gmaps/google
// require active_admin_map_index
//= require_tree .


$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
     header:
     left: "prev,next today",
     center: "title",
     right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
     defaultView: "month",
     height: 500,
     slotMinutes: 15,
     eventSources: ["/events/info"],
     timeFormat: "h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ",
     dragOpacity: "0.5"
  });
});
```

active_admin.js

```
// require index_as_calendar/application
//= require active_admin/base
//= require jquery-ui
//= require select2
// require underscore
// require autoselect

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('input.hasDatetimePicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShow: function () {
      setTimeout(
       function () {
          $('#ui-datepicker-div').css("z-index", "3000");
        }, 100
        function () {
          $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
        },
        function () {
          newAutoSelect = new AutoSelect(input: $('#q_id_eq'))
          newAutoSelect.init();
    )}
  });
 }
)};
```

my application.scss

```
"*= require jquery-ui
 *= require jquery-ui/sortable
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require fullcalendar
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
 @import "active_admin/mixins";
 @import "active_admin/base";
 //@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
 //@import "font-awesome";
 @import "active_admin_datetimepicker";
 @import "fullcalendar";"
```

my partial gemfile

```
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0'
gem "active_admin-sortable_tree"
gem 'active_admin_importable'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'activeadmin_addons'
gem 'active_admin_datetimepicker'
gem 'active_admin_role'
gem 'active_admin-duplicatable'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.2'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'high_voltage', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'rails-assets-jquery', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-datatables', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.5'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: 
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
```

Comment: I mucked up my pipeline with too many different gems trying to do the same thing so I did a bit of a purge and just used the gems i needed. Not sure what the exact problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up my assets pipeline that was in vendor as well, too many conflicts. Purged gems that were in conflict, and cleaned up code. allgood.